# What is the best practice for the scope of variables in a class

Tags: java, variables, static, scope, local

### My teachers source code was published and i was confused when i saw this:

New local variables where instantiated from a static variable, the variable was then used in a method and passed as an argument to another method, to then set its new value to the same static variable that the copy was based on. Since the scope of a static variable will be accessible throughout the class, why not access the static variable directly from every method within that class?

Why do this:

```
public class Calculator {

    private JTextField displayText;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String input = displayText.getText();    

        if (something == right) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                enterNumber(input);    
            }
        }
    }

    public void enterNumber(String input) {  

        displayText.setText(input); 
    }
}
```

If you can just:

```
public class Calculator {

    private JTextField displayText;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (something == right) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                enterNumber();
            }
        }
    }

    public void enterNumber() {

        String localVar = "Kitten";
        displayText.setText(localVar);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the `static` keyword here anywhere. What has `static` got to do with this? Are you just misusing the term or have you pasted the wrong code?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you be a bit clearer? There are no static elements in that (Java) code.

Comment: Your two examples don't do the same thing. What's the question again?

Comment: The point is that `static` variable may be changed externally at any time - if you pass a copy of that value to your methods you are guaranteed to process the value as it was at the point of original call...

Comment: Generally with variables scope - use as narrow a scope as you can (is **not** 100% best practice but you should start with that)...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this exact example you are right, there is no point in having a parameter in your enter number method.

but when you begin to work on more complex programs you start to notice that you end up using the same functionality over and over again, in which you can have a method with parameters, such that you can perform the same action with slight variation.

also it is easier to read for other people if you have a method with parameters, since all you have to do is say, "ok i call the method and send it blank, it sets the value to whatever i sent it.", instead of saying "ok i call the method, now lets see what the method does."

if your code works then it is not bad code. but if it works and is easy to read then it is good code.